How can I properly add an event listener to a series of asynchronous functions in Javascript/JQuery?
I'm struggling with the order of operations with asynchronous functions and event listeners in Javascript. I have a script with a function that fetches a list of publicly-traded companies from an API endpoint ('api/company_list'). After the data is returned, it dynamically updates a dropdown menu with the list of company symbols and names, and also displays the name of the first company in the data array on the webpage. Finally, it passes that first company's symbol as a template literal to another URL in order to fetch that company's price data from a second API endpoint and display it on a chart.
I can accomplish the above by simply grabbing the first returned company from the company list data using it's index (data[0].symbol) when the page loads.
But what I need to know is - how do I incorporate an event listener so that when a different company is selected from the dropdown, it updates both the company name on the webpage and passes the newly-selected symbol to the second URL ('api/price_data') to select the chart data?
And can I do this all in the same script?
I can do one script that runs the code below when the page loads and a second script that runs the same code encapsulated inside of a function that runs when the dropdown selection changes, but this seemed highly duplicative. There's got to be a way to streamline it.
I've tried adding an onChange event listener for my dropdown ("mySelect") in the code below, but since the dropdown is populated dynamically as part of a promise, the data isn't yet available to use when I tried to grab the newly-selected value and pass it to both the page and the second URL. Clearly I'm misunderstanding the flow async functions.
I feel like this is probably a fairly simple fix, but so far I've been unable to find a solution. Thanks in advance for your help. I'd be happy to provide additional information or answer any questions.
function getData(url) {
    return fetch(url)
        .then(response => {
            if(!response.ok) {
                throw new Error('Bad Network Request');
            }
            return response.json();
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Fetch error:', error);
            throw error;
        });
}

//fetch the list of companies from an API endpoint and dynamically populate the dropdown list:
getData('/api/company_list')
        .then(function myFunction(data) {
        let option = '';            
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            option += '<option value="' + data[i].symbol + '">' + data[i].stock_rank + ' - ' + data[i].company_name + '  (' + data[i].symbol + ')' + '</option>';
        }
        
        const inputElement = $("#mySelect");
        inputElement.append(option);
        
    
        let firstCompany = data[0].symbol;
        
        $("company").html(data[0].company_name);
        
        const priceUrl = `/api/price_data/?symbol=${firstCompany}`;
        
        getData(priceUrl)
            .then(function myFunction(priceData) {
                
                //add the price data to a chart
            });
});



Consolidate and reuse the get.
I use a data attribute for faster access to the company name
Something like this
const getData = (url, callback) =>
  fetch(url)
    .then(response => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Bad Network Request');
      }
      return response.json(); 
    })
    .then(data => {
      callback(data); // Pass the data to the callback
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Fetch error:', error);
      throw error;
    });
  const getActiveButton = () => document.querySelector('#weekly.active') ? `weekly_prices` : `daily_prices';
const updateCompanyInfo = companyData => {
const { symbol, company_name } = companyData;
  $("company").html(company_name);
  const priceUrl = `/api/${getActiveButton()}/?symbol=${symbol}`;
  getData(priceUrl, updateChart);
};

const updateChart = priceData => {
  // Logic to update the chart with priceData
  console.log('Price data:', priceData);
};

$('#mySelect').on('change', function () {
  const selectedSymbol = $(this).val();
  const selectedCompany = $(this).find(`option[value="${selectedSymbol}"]`).data('company'); /
  updateCompanyInfo({ symbol: selectedSymbol, company_name: selectedCompany });
});

getData('/api/company_list', data => {
  const options = data.map(
    company =>
      `<option value="${company.symbol}" data-company="${company.company_name}">
          ${company.stock_rank} - ${company.company_name} (${company.symbol})
      </option>`
  ).join('');

  $("#mySelect").html(options); // Replace the dropdown options
  updateCompanyInfo(data[0]); // Initialize with the first company
});


Thanks for the quick response! I'll take a stab at this over the weekend and let you know how it goes. I appreciate your time and help.

Works like a charm. Much appreciated!

You should not attach duplicated event handlers inside the .then() otherwise, every time you call getData you'll add uselessly another listener - and all the attached jobs. Either use that antipattern with .off() or (rather) move it out of that callback. (PS, why not use async/await?)

Why have you used data-name="${company.company_name}"?

I use the data-attribute for faster access. I could regex it out of the text() but if OP wants to change the text, then the regex has to change too. Anyway, I have change the code which was clunky.

@mplungjan looks neater & cleaner now! PS, why $('#mySelect').on('change', function () { twice?

Thanks for spotting that. Paste error

Thanks for the additional comments and updated code!  Can I ask for additional functionality to be added to the above code? What I'd like to do is add buttons to my page called btnDaily and btnWeekly. On page load, btnDaily should be active and then I'd like to be able to toggle between the buttons. Depending upon which button is clicked, and therefore active, I'd like to fetch price data from two different URLs:  const dailyUrl = api/daily_prices/?symbol=${symbol};  const weeklyUrl = api/weekly_prices/?symbol=${symbol};. This would go in the function to update a chart with price data.

See update......
